Bug on VichUploaderBundle in symfony 6.4
I created all as shown, installed the bundle, created Media Object entity and src/Serializer/MediaObjectNormalizer.php, showed format in api-platform.yaml. But got the result of "Deserialization for the format "multipart" is not supported." with status code 400.
Here is my entity:
namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[Vich\Uploadable]
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource(
    types: ['https://schema.org/MediaObject'],
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection(),
        new Post(
            inputFormats: ['multipart' => ['multipart/form-data']],
            openapi: new Model\Operation(
                requestBody: new Model\RequestBody(
                    content: new \ArrayObject([
                        'multipart/form-data' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                'type' => 'object',
                                'properties' => [
                                    'file' => [
                                        'type' => 'string',
                                        'format' => 'binary'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ])
                )
            ),
        )
    ],
    outputFormats: ['jsonld' => ['application/ld+json']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['media_object:read']]
)]
class MediaObject
{
    #[ORM\Id, ORM\Column, ORM\GeneratedValue]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ApiProperty(writable: false, types: ['https://schema.org/contentUrl'])]
    #[Groups(['media_object:read'])]
    public ?string $contentUrl = null;

    #[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'media_object', fileNameProperty: 'filePath')]
    #[Assert\NotNull]
    public ?File $file = null;

    #[ApiProperty(writable: false)]
    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    public ?string $filePath = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}


and this is api_platform.yaml:
api_platform:
    title: Hello Api
    version: 1.0.0
    formats:
        multipart: ['multipart/form-data']
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
        json: ['application/json']
    docs_formats:
        jsonld: ['application/ld+json']
        jsonopenapi: ['application/vnd.openapi+json']
        html: ['text/html']
    defaults:
        stateless: true
        cache_headers:
            vary: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization', 'Origin']
        extra_properties:
            standard_put: true
            rfc_7807_compliant_errors: true
    keep_legacy_inflector: false
    use_symfony_listeners: true
    swagger:
        api_keys:
            JWT:
                name: Authorization
                type: header


I created
api/src/Encoder/MultipartDecoder.php, api/src/Serializer/UploadedFileDenormalizer.php and media folder in public and the issue was solved
